# C# EventLog. Remove selected EventLogEntry

Tags: c#, event-log

I want to delete entry in every iteration. Can i do it? Here is my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    el = new EventLog();
    el.Log = "XMLWatcherLog";
    el.Source = "XMLWatcherSource";


    string netStr =string.Empty;

    foreach (EventLogEntry entry in el.Entries)
    {
        netStr += "<item>" + "<path>" + entry.Message + "</path>";

       // here i want to delete entry
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use foreach because you are going to modify the list (delete entry). For first iteration code will work fine but on second iteration it will throw exception saying that 'collection was modified'. Instead of foreach you can use simple for loop.

Comment: you said that i must write code as it :
            for (int i = 0; i < el.Entries.Count; i++)
            {
                //but how i will delete it?
            }

Comment: Well, there is EventLog.Delete method. You can use this method. Here is the page which can give you more information. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twdecbsx(VS.80).aspx

Comment: it will delete all log which name is MyCustomLog. but not selected entry from collection